# Can I use jsp scriptlets in jspx files?

Tags: java, jsp, jspx

Is there a way I can use the jsp scriptlets in jspx files ? Writing like this `<%="hello"%>`  in jspx file gave me errors. Please help.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`<jsp:scriptlet>` and `<jsp:expression>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPX3.html) for this. It has however to be wrapped in an ugly `<[CDATA[` block.

Using *scriptlets* is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) anyway. I'd forget about it all and put Java code in Java classes.

Comment: +1 for added up. Thanks for sharing. Sure, I will avoid using scriptlets in jsp or jspx files.

Answer (score 5):

Just for my own sanity and record: (Oracle really don't make a good job of explaining this).  Strictly for debugging: (spring's documentation is so detailed, I get lost)

You can use:

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
  <![CDATA[
    java.util.Enumeration e=request.getAttributeNames();
    while(e.hasMoreElements())
    {
      String name=(String)e.nextElement();
      out.print(name);
      out.print(":");
      Object value=request.getAttribute(name);
      out.print(value);
      out.print("<br/>");
    }
  ]]>
</jsp:scriptlet>
```